# Cpanel doesn't find my bootsrap.php file in paypal api (built in netbeans)

Tags: php, netbeans, configuration, cpanel, paypal-sandbox

I built a PayPal API in Netbeans with a local environment server (xampp). The API worked properly in the local environment. When I upload the files to the Cpanel environment I got the following error when i type the payment button:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
/////////
Message: require_once(/home/roeyfr/public_html/A.T_system/application/libraries/paypal-php-sdk/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: controllers/Paypal_controller.php

Line Number: 6

Backtrace:

File: /home/roeyfr/public_html/A.T_system/application/controllers/Paypal_controller.php
Line: 6
Function: _error_handler
////

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/roeyfr/public_html/A.T_system/application/libraries/paypal-php-sdk/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/roeyfr/public_html/A.T_system/application/controllers/Paypal_controller.php on line 9
```

The code is:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/paypal-php-sdk/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/bootstrap.php'); // require paypal files

use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much need to troubleshoot and solve that type of file path / file nonexistence error on your own; it's not an issue for the Stackoverflow community to remotely debug.

Moreover, the [PayPal-PHP-SDK is deprecated and should not be used for any new integrations](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK#deprecation-notice). You should be using the v2 Checkout-PHP-SDK.